# Nuxt 3 useFetch -- how to create reactive fields from returned data object?

Tags: nuxtjs3, nuxt3, usefetch

In my setup, I have the following:

```
const{ data, error } =  useFetch("http://localhost:8080/articles", { query: { page: dataPage }})
```

where `datapage` is a ref.  This refetches whenever I change `datapage`, so that works well.

Now I want to get a field out of the `data` variable.  Specifically, this works:

```
<div>{{ data.pageable }}</div>
```

But I want to do this:

```
const pageable = toRef(data.pageable)

...

<div>{{ pageable }}</div>
```

This returns nothing (undefined).  I also tried:

```
const { pageable } = toRefs(data)
```

with no luck.

How can I make a field of the `data` into a reactive value?
Basically, I'm trying to avoid referencing "data" each time I want to access a field of the fetched data object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**. I completely missunderstood OP's question.

If you are trying to avoid referencing the `data`, you can use the computed property.

`~/pages/index.vue`

```js
<script setup>
const dataPage = ref( 0 )
const { data } = await useFetch( '/api/get-the-query', {
    query: { page: dataPage }
} )
const pageable = computed( () => data.value.pageable )

</script>
<template>
    <div>
        <div>
            Current pageable is: {{ pageable }}
        </div>
        <button
            v-for="num in 10"
            :key="num"
            @click.prevent="dataPage = num"
        >{{ num }}</button>
    </div>
</template>
<style scoped lang="css"></style>
```

API example
`~/server/api/get-the-query`

```js
export default defineEventHandler((event) => {
    return {
        pageable: getQuery(event).page
    }
})
```

Comment: No that's not the question!  The question is, how can I make "pageable" the reactive element, rather than "data.pageable" ?  I don't want to reference the "data" piece each time.  In your sample, you have "data?.pageable" and that is what I am trying to avoid in this exercise.

Comment: Apologies for misunderstanding your question. I'm editing my answer

Comment: If you are trying to avoid referencing the `data`, you can use computed. `const pageable = computed( () => data.value.pageable )`.

Comment: Thank you! It was the "value" that screwed me up.